# Custom checkbox (radio) not centred while zooming

Tags: css, checkbox, google-chrome-extension, radio-button, zooming

I am writing an extension for chrome browser. A block with two custom checkboxes and labels are added to the page I need. The problem is that when scaling the page, the internal selection of the radio starts to behave strangely,changes shape and moves out of the center
[image: Checkboxes page scaling]

I can't figure out what is causing the problem. I've tried different positioning options for the before element, but it only works for one page scale. ChatGPT and the Indians from YouTube did not help. You are my last hope :( Here is my script.js code and styles style.css

script.js

```
const user_abuser_block = document.createElement('div');
user_abuser_block.classList.add('user_abuser_block');
user_abuser_block.style.zIndex = '9999';
document.body.appendChild(user_abuser_block);

const checkbox1 = document.createElement('input');
checkbox1.classList.add('checkbox-container');
checkbox1.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
checkbox1.setAttribute('checked', true);

const enabledLabel = document.createElement('label');
enabledLabel.classList.add('label-container');
enabledLabel.appendChild(checkbox1);
enabledLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Enabled'));
user_abuser_block.appendChild(enabledLabel);

const checkbox2 = document.createElement('input');
checkbox2.classList.add('checkbox-container');
checkbox2.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

const disabledLabel = document.createElement('label');
disabledLabel.classList.add('label-container');
disabledLabel.appendChild(checkbox2);
disabledLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Disabled'));
user_abuser_block.appendChild(disabledLabel);
```

style.css

```
.user_abuser_block {
  position: fixed;
  top: 67px;
  left: 528px;
  width: 223px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  padding-top: 12px;;
  padding-left: 12px;;
}

.checkbox-container {
  left: -4px;
  top: -1px;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.05em;
  height: 1.05em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0.1em solid #656565;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.checkbox-container:checked {
  position: relative;
  border: 0.1em solid #71aaeb;
}

.checkbox-container:checked::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: center;
  width: 0.6em;
  height: 0.6em;
  background-color: #71aaeb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(25%, 25%);
}

.label-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately the code is incomplete. Can you provide a reproducible sample?

Comment: Ok, i updated my code. Now it's absolutely full

Comment: "ChatGPT and the Indians from YouTube did not help" - Now that's a surprise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there at any zoom level, it's just not easily visible at lower zoom levels.

To make the positioning absolutely accurate make it and the sizing relative i.e. using % values. Note especially that to center a before pseudo element you can give it top and left values of 50% (this is relative to the 'parent') then translate -50% (this is relative to its own dimensions).

```html
<body>aeh
</body>
<script>
  const user_abuser_block = document.createElement('div');
  user_abuser_block.classList.add('user_abuser_block');
  user_abuser_block.style.zIndex = '9999';
  document.body.appendChild(user_abuser_block);

  const checkbox1 = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox1.classList.add('checkbox-container');
  checkbox1.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  checkbox1.setAttribute('checked', true);

  const enabledLabel = document.createElement('label');
  enabledLabel.classList.add('label-container');
  enabledLabel.appendChild(checkbox1);
  enabledLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Enabled'));
  user_abuser_block.appendChild(enabledLabel);

  const checkbox2 = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox2.classList.add('checkbox-container');
  checkbox2.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

  const disabledLabel = document.createElement('label');
  disabledLabel.classList.add('label-container');
  disabledLabel.appendChild(checkbox2);
  disabledLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Disabled'));
  user_abuser_block.appendChild(disabledLabel);
</script>
<style>
  .user_abuser_block {
    position: fixed;
    top: 67px;
    rleft: 528px;
    width: 223px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
  }
  
  .checkbox-container {
    left: -4px;
    top: -1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1.05em;
    height: 1.05em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0.1em solid #656565;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 2px;
  }
  
  .checkbox-container:checked {
    position: relative;
    border: 0.1em solid #71aaeb;
  }
  
  .checkbox-container:checked::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #71aaeb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .label-container {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: This code also does not work correctly. I run code snippet and still see problems when scaling elements  :(
https://imgur.com/a/kMz3q77

Comment: @gle6 that's interesting. It's fine for me (laptop Edge W10). What device/browser/OS are you using?

Comment: PC, Windows 11, google chrome and microsoft edge :(
Just checked and second PC with Windows 10, still broken.
Zoom 175% https://imgur.com/a/moWoHIu

Comment: Just tried Safari IOS and it is slightly off center on that. Is it dependent on screen pixel ratio - placement being a pixel or so off?